# Is it possible for an extension to be in the URL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have never developed for Chrome before and I really like the feature of pressing tab on the Chrome url to search within that website that you are about to go to.

However, is it possible to make an extension that allows you to type something into the URL and then press tab to make it trigger an action?

Comment: This is what you can do with an extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requisite API is [`chrome.omnibox`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox).

What can it do: you can have a preset "keyword" that you enter in the URL bar, and after than everything that you type after the keyword gets sent to the extension, and it can offer "suggestions" for the omnibar.